# Getting Top (starting no , Ending no) rows from sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using Grid view in my asp.net page and I'm fetching data from SQL Server and placing in my grid view.

Now my problem is, I'm using paging and placing 50 rows per page in Grid view. I would like to fetch top 50 rows from database in the start up and bind to the Grid View and when i click on next page, then again go to the database and fetch Second Top 50 rows and bind to GV. and this process hasto continue until last row is fetched from Database.

Can you tell me How to write Query in achieving this??

Comment: there are plenty https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&biw=1366&bih=624&noj=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=paging+using+row_number&oq=paging+using+row_number&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30j0i5i30l2j0i8i30j0i22.4665698.4670056.0.4670667.23.21.0.2.2.0.232.2782.6j8j6.20.0...0.0...1c.1.hA4jOJSN7Bk

Comment: Solved, solved, solved, oh so many times. Please read these comments and the article they refer to: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you will have two parameters passed to this query, `@pageNum` and `@pageSize`, then you can do this:

```
With ranked AS   --- Or you can make it a view
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderField) AS RowNum,  * 
   FROM YourTableReference
)
SELECT *   --Your fields here
FROM Ranked
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
                 AND (@PageNum * @PageSize)
ORDER BY SomeField
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79951/pagining-in-sql-server)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'. - I'n using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @KrishnaThota, It should work with no error, check your syntax. Also you can see a live demo, see my edit.

Comment: `;With RowNums AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Order_Date DESC) AS RowNum, * FROM @tbl
)
SET @MaxPageSize=(SELECT CEILING((CAST(MAX(RowNum) AS FLOAT))/(CAST(@PageSize AS FLOAT))) FROM RowNums)` Why is this not possible?? It Returns `Incorrent Syntax near the keyword SET`

Comment: @KrishnaThota you can't set the variable after the definition of the CTE. Try to set that variable before the definition of the CTE.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sproc

```
sp_fetcrangeofrecords
@st int,
@ed int

As
BEGIN
WITH CTE as (select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn,* from your table)

select col1,col2,... from table where rn between @st and @ed
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Read more about SQL paging, there are several approaches http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19611/Paging-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try [Paging GridView with ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12962/Paging-GridView-with-ROW_NUMBER) and you will get the idea as how to do it.

Also [SQL Server - Server-side paging with Row_number() function](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10434/sql-server-server-side-paging-with-rownumber-function.aspx) will help.